# Git extensions "Create new repository" not working

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am a long time user of Git and Git Extensions.

Recently I updated both Git and Git Extensions (on windows, using chocolatey) to versions 1.9.4.20140929 and 2.48.03.

Most things still work well. But, when I bring up the file explorer in a folder with no git repository and right click and choose `GitEx Create new repository` (the GUI version of `git init`) I am shown this

[image]

This seems wrong. It should show something like this
[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Submit a bug report to the Git Extensions folks? It appears that, while it presents the option in the context menu as required, and the executable's help message lists the subcommand as supported, either it is not actually supported/doesn't work right, or the context menu mechanism somehow mangles the actual command that gets run...

Comment: @twalberg I have now submitted an [issue on the Git Extensions repo](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2564).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was [a bug](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2564).

I have submitted [a pull request to fix it, which has been accepted](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/2565).

Comment: I just downloaded the latest 2.48.03 which continues to have the bug..Is this commit going to be included in next release?

Comment: There is still no build that includes this and I can't for the life of me get the project to build. Can anyone build it for us?

Comment: This bug fixed in 2.48.05 and better